# How to use a Python list in a condition for Mysql

Tags: python, jquery, mysql, list, join

i have this list in python:

```
list_accounts =['30000451728022100000127007', '0011801410', '30024891622032100004168003']
```

And I want to use it in a query like this:

```
select a.order_id, transaction_status, gmv
from master.fulfillment a
inner join master.txns b
on a.order_id = b.order_id
where a.account_number in ('30000451728022100000127007', '0011801410','30024553922032100000439005');
```

So far i got this:

```
q1 = "select a.order_id, transaction_status, gmv "\
     "from master.fulfillment a "\
     "inner join master.txns b "\
     "on a.order_id = b.order_id "\
     "where a.account_number in "+ list_accounts + ""

cursor.execute(q1)
```

How can I put the list in the query to have the proper sinstaxis ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a string containing as many placeholders as the length of the list, and use that in the `WHERE` condition. Then use `list_accounts` as the parameters that fill in the placeholders.

You also need `()` around the `in` list.

```
placeholders = ','.join(['%s'] * len(list_accounts))
q1 = f"""
    select a.order_id, transaction_status, gmv
    from master.fulfillment a
    inner join master.txns b
    on a.order_id = b.order_id
    where a.account_number in ({placeholders})"""
cursor.execute(q1, list_accounts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting and `.join()`:

```
query = """select .......... where a.account_number in ({});""".format(', '.join(list_accounts))
```